# ASP.net putting a dataitem in a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, web-controls, datarepeater

I've got a:

- Data repeater
- Control in the repeater

And I'd like to put some values into the controls.  At the moment I have a control in it as:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ArchiveEntryRepeater">
    snip
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" ToolTip="Comment on Some Entry Title Here" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Blog/7/How-to-know-when-this/Comments">
        <strong><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Comments")%></strong> Comments
    </asp:HyperLink>
    snip
</asp:Repeater>
```

Which works fine, but I want to put

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title")%>
```

Into the NavigateURL property of the Hyperlink.  Just putting it in doesn't seem to work!

Comment: Can you show the hyperlink code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always bind on the back end using the event [itemdatabound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx).  It has some advantages especially where the data is not a neat view or needs some type of major manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

Try enclosing your NavigateURL in apostrophes instead of double quotes to not confuse the ASP.NET parser:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title")%>' [...]>[...]</asp:HyperLink>
```

This might be your issue.

Comment: Duh, I couldn't test it because I'm at work, what happens if you try with NavigateUrl (instead of URL)? It used to work for me (except when there was text before the `<%#`).

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to loose the  control and replace it with an html anchor control like this:

```
 <asp:Repeater>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a id="HyperLink1" title="Comment on Some Entry Title Here" href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title")%>'
                style="font-weight: bold">'<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Comments")%>'</a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Once the server renders a hyperlink to the client there is generally no reason to have it "runat='server'" . The purpose is to navigate to another page so the overhead of using an asp:HyperLink vs. an nchor is wasted.